# Windows 8 phone application runs out of memory

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I have a windows phone(Lumia 920) app that deals with a lot of images(10 or so full resolution) that is being captured by the camera.

It is then being sent asynchronously to a service(wcf) and then discarded by the phone. However when the wifi is a little slow the photos in the memory of the phone gets bottle up and an out of memory exception occurs.

This is not an app that will be on the store so I just want to increase the available usage on the phone.

I have tried to set

```
<Requirements>
     <Requirement Name="ID_REQ_MEMORY_300" />
</Requirements>
```

yet I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried saving the images to isolatedStorage, disposing of the in-memory objects, then recovering each image in turn form isolatedStorage to memory, uploading it, then, when you are sure that it has been uploaded,  disposing of the isolatedStorage version?

Comment: Could work I guess. Will then just have to change the saving mechanism into some form of queue so that it does not try to load all images at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change it much. If you want to request the maximum amount of memory though you would need to add `ID_FUNCCAP_EXTEND_MEM` to your requirements.

```
<App>
…
  <Requirements>
    <Requirement Name="ID_REQ_FRONTCAMERA"/>
  </Requirements>
  <FunctionalCapabilities>
    <FunctionalCapability Name="ID_FUNCCAP_EXTEND_MEM"/>
  </FunctionalCapabilities>
</App>
```

The requirement you're setting simply disallows your app from being installed on a phone with lower memory. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681682%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more info.